# Вертикальное выравнивание в Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

Делаю через *Bootstrap 3*, нужно выравнивание **нескольких** (любых объектов) с чётным-нечётным количеством (**не строчные**!). Примеры с прописыванием точных размеров в px не предлагать, только в %.
Вот пример кода:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
                <div class="kostnormaltext">Подсказки</div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="center-block">
                    <img class="center-block img-responsive img-rounded" src="{% static 'img/scrip_key.jpg' %}" id="fillimage" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                <div class="">
                    <button onclick="" type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="buttoncheck">Звук</button>
                    <button onclick="" type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="buttoncheck">Проверить</button>
                    <button onclick="" type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="buttoncheck">Следующая нота</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

При этом нужно сделать так, чтобы эти элементы были всегда вертикально в центре своей колонки, независимо от масштабирования экрана. но зависимо от общего размера всего ряда!.
По-сути есть 1 ряд в нём 3 колонки (разделены тёмно-жёлтым цветом) и синяя центральная линия, к которой нужно выравнивать (не важно какой блок двигать, parent-зелёный или child-красный).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: flex-box Вам в помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте возможности флекса. Если задать контейнеру с классом **row** свойство display: flex, то его дочерние элементы можно выравнивать вертикально по середине через свойство align-items: center.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.item1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.item2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;      
}
.item3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item1">
  </div>
  <div class="item2">
  </div>
  <div class="item3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Чтобы не переопределять глобально класс row, создайте дополнительный класс row-flex, и добавьте его к элементу <div class="row row-flex"></div>. Так вы просто расширите возможности бутстрапа для конкретного проекта.

Comment: Нет, не получилось, эти 3 кнопки ну никак не становятся по центру колонки...

Comment: Полагаю, что в вашем случае надо внимательнее поработать с кодом, ведь могут оказывать влияния стили родительских элементов. То есть, приведенный выше пример работает однозначно. Работать некорректно он может лишь из-за влияния внешних стилей или вертки. Воспользуйтесь инструментом F12 вашего браузера, чтобы исследовать код.

Comment: Если добавляю такой класс row-flex в основной ряд - то все колонки ряда пропадают (в F12 показывает ряд и объекты, но их не видно), если добавляю его перед колонкой, где находятся кнопки - они выводятся построчно, накладываются на колонку рядом.

Comment: Насколько я вижу по коду в вопросе там нет закрывающего div'а у первого же элемента после row. Это вполне может вызывать сбой при использовании флекса.

Comment: Просто код не правильно отредактирован в самом stack (сейчас поправлю). По-сути вот такое распределение: к левому краю прижата 1/12 колонка, далее идёт колонка 9/12 с офсэтом 1 и дочерним оффсэтом 1, далее 1/12 колонка прижатая к правому краю. И весь код, который я скидывал: 9/12 как раз. В WebStorm все перепроверил, dev закрыты.

Comment: Сложно сейчас сказать, в чем причина. Надо изучать конкретный код. Явно, что в нем закралась какая-то ошибка, которая мешает реализоваться флексу. Кстати, не в тему поправлю, но все же вкладывать в элемент .col-* еще один элемент с .col-* не обернув его в .row - противоречит рекомендациям бутстрапа. Сетка съезжает.